# is there any way to get category of instagram business account from graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

i want get some information about Instagram business account from graph api. but i don't find any way to know about category of account. this code give me some information but not about category.

```
{ig_id}?fields=business_discovery.username({username}){Bbiography,followers_count,follows_count,media_count,website}
```

thank for your help

Answer (score 1):

That does not seem to be possible.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/#returnable-fields lists all the available fields you can request for an `IG User` object - and any sort of category is *not* one of them.